# HTML - javascript is there any way to force a POST to come from the server instead of the user`s browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, networking, webhooks

we are running a javascript on an EC2 instance which will generate a webhook to interface with API gateway, running on the browser the API will need to be public, so we would need to find a way to secure this.
There are a few options which we are exploring, but the easiest would be to have the request sent to the API gateway from the instance instead of the user's browser, so my question is if there is any way in HTML, javascript, ajax etc... to force the request to be sent from the server instead of the user's browser?
Thanks

Comment: Browsers won't send AJAX requests to a different domain unless you enable CORS on your server. So they have to do it from the server and you don't have to do anything in your API.

Comment: @barmar, thank you for your reply, is this something which can be setup from the request?
We are using this to POST the request:
$.ajax({url: 'OUR_URL', type: 'POST',data: { value: 'value' }});

so you mean we should setup the mode to be `no-cors`?

Comment: You don't have to set up anything. The default is to not allow CORS. The server has to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow it.

Comment: yes, that is correct, but if we don`t enable cors we will get an error from the browser and I assumed this was because the browser can`t get the server to send the request on its behalf? sorry if the question sounds silly.

Comment: I am kinda new to this and probably missing parts of the core operation, understand the whole point with js is to run on the browser, when we do the ajax POST from html running on the browser, will this force the POST request to be sent from the server instead? Within the AWS infrastructures there are multiple rules to block traffic from IPs and Ports, so I am trying to understand how this is supposed to work and then I can look at the right place.

Comment: but I believe I didn`t get what you meant because thinking about this, I can`t see how ajax on the browser can force the request to be sent from the server. :)

Comment: The browser refuses to send AJAX to a different domain from the web page itself. Since the browser won't do it by itself, JavaScript has to send the AJAX to a server script in the same domain, which then sends to your API.

Comment: Google "AJAX same origin policy".

Comment: ok, it doesn`t work on my application, but before I look into it, if I understand this correctly, the browser will basically send an HTTP request (so it will come from the user machine`s IP) to the server hosting the web app, it will indicate the domain and what is the resource it needs the server to get (or post) on its behalf. This HTTP request to the server is not secured whatsoever, anyone having looking at the source code in the browser  could easily mimic this without physically been on the webpage at all, correct?

Comment: Please stop using backticks in place of apostrophe :) It makes code formatting in your comments.

Comment: Yes, they can mimic it from their server, not the browser.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to protect. If you have an API, you naturally publish the way to call it. The users of the API call it from their server, not the browser. The browser calls *their* server, not your server.

Comment: There won't be any secrets in the application in the browser. The secret key is on their server, and end users can't see it.

Comment: ok, I got this now. Thanks